# Best way to set few types of accounts in ZendFramework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks

I would like to start first serious project with ZF.

Needed 3 types of account with different privileges.

Admin (1 acc)
Managers
Salesman

How do do it? 3 tables in DB, 3 models and 3 login forms?

How is possible to check via php code if user is admin, or manager, or salesman?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ZF2 I'd recommend using ZfcUser and ZfcRbac (Role Based Access Controll) modules in your application. The pretty much provide the functionality straight out of the tin! Just add them to your composer.json file and install them and follow the install/setup instructions in the relevant modules. See: https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser and https://github.com/ZF-Commons/zfc-rbac

Comment: You didn't specify that in your question. You need to be more specific in your question.